# What is an Interceptor in dart?

Tags: dart

I frequently come across the Interceptor base class in the dart docs, but the link is broken. Does anyone know what is an interceptor?

For instance the Storage class derives from Interceptor
http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/Storage.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you open the declaration of any such type in DartEditor, it turns out that it is actually derived from `NativeFieldWrapperClass1` class.

`NativeFieldWrapperClass1` class is used as the base class for types which have a native implementation in environments which embed Dart VM, e.g. classes which wrap DOM elements - canvas DOM element is implemented in browser and wrapped into `CanvasElement` Dart class.

Instances of such types have their peers in native implementation (`CanvasElement` instance has native peer C/C++ object in the browser). Deriving from `NativeFieldWrapperClass1` ensures they have a slot where embedders can store a pointer to the peer object - native data. This is done with embedder API (`Dart_SetNativeInstanceField` function).

Comment: They inherit from `NativeFieldWrapperClass*` in the VM and from `Interceptor` in dart2js. The documentation generator uses dart2js.